# set matpllotlib default style using rc file

Tags: matplotlib

Is there an easy way to set the matplotlib style to dark_background by default using something like the matplotlibrc?

I can do this in the scripts using:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.style.use('dark_background')
```

However I would like this to persist for other scripts ... I know this can be done in theory by manually copying all the styles over into the matplotlibrc file 1 setting at a time, but I would like to just set it in one line like the code above if possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the predesigned `dark_background` style with `plt.style.use("dark_background")`, refer below example. You can find more documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

plt.style.use("dark_background")

x = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=50)
y = np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=50)

N = 50
colors = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x,y,c=colors)
plt.xlim(0,1000) # This is to limit x-axis
plt.ylim(-5,5) # This is to limit y-axis
plt.grid()
```

[image: OutputImage]

you may set the respective `rcParams` manually.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({
    "lines.color": "white",
    "patch.edgecolor": "white",
    "text.color": "black",
    "axes.facecolor": "white",
    "axes.edgecolor": "lightgray",
    "axes.labelcolor": "white",
    "xtick.color": "white",
    "ytick.color": "white",
    "grid.color": "lightgray",
    "figure.facecolor": "black",
    "figure.edgecolor": "black",
    "savefig.facecolor": "black",
    "savefig.edgecolor": "black"})

x = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=50)
y = np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=50)

N = 50
colors = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x,y,c=colors)
plt.xlim(0,1000) # This is to limit x-axis
plt.ylim(-5,5) # This is to limit y-axis
plt.grid()
```

[image: OutputImage2]

Comment: right so the only way to do it is to set the individual rc params one by one in the matplotlibrc file ?

Comment: @othane : does `matplotlib` predesigned `dark_background` doesn't work for you ?

Comment: it does indeed work .. but I don't want to have to call `plt.style.use('dark_background')` every time I start python, I want it to default to dark_background. ATM I have solved this by copying the `dark_background.mplstyle` contents into the `matplotlibrc`, but it would be nicer if I could specify to use this in the `matplotlibrc` so if the `dark_background.mplstyle` is updated my style will update too

Comment: You can [refer this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) detailed documentation. You can customize this as per the their [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I have been using as a source ... i was just wondering if there was a one line to include the `mplstyle` into the `matplotlibrc` rather than specifying every single style ... it looks like the answer is no

Comment: This does not answer the actual question